# skos broader and narrow inverse not working

Tags: graphdb, skos

I have setup GraphDB SE trial version and trying out inference functionality with OWL2-RL ruleset. I have built a simple SKOS knowledge with a single broader relationship. Some how, when I try to query for narrower relationship am not getting any results. Am I going wrong in the usage ?

Insertion:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

INSERT DATA {  
        ex:mammals rdf:type skos:Concept;
                   skos:prefLabel "mammals"@en;

        ex:animals rdf:type skos:Concept;
                   skos:prefLabel "animals"@en;
                   skos:broader ex:mammals .
}
```

Query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

select * where {
    ?s skos:narrower ?o .
}
```

In the query result I don't see any response. Shouldn't it return below result -
ex:mammals skos:narrower ex:animals

Comment: Add `skos:broader owl:inverseOf skos:narrower`. Make sure `>>` is enabled.

Comment: even better, load the SKOS ontology into your repositoryso  to introduce some meaning on what actually is `skos:broader` or `skos:narrower` and the relationship between these

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question and the OP is correct: Although the [official SKOS reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/skos-reference/) explicitly states that `skos:broader` and `skos:narrower` are inverse, [the actual RDF implementation](http://www.w3.org/TR/skos-reference/skos.rdf) does not include this statement. However, properties `skos:broaderTransitive` and `skos:narrowerTransitive` are declared as inverse.

And, although not relevant to the original question, the implementation does not state properties `skos:topConceptOf` and `skos:hasTopConcept` as inverse either.